# why does the connection to webSocket fail Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, signalr

I'm new to websocket..
first, I installed signalR and added 'using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets;' in the code behind..
second, I tried to make websocket connection to my site on the client side, but at run time there's the following error:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4653/showDiagrams.aspx/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200..
does somebody know how to help me?

Comment: AFAIK, build-in websockets only works on Windows 8 or higher. For windows 7 and below, you should use a 3rd party library. (like fleck https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck)

Comment: ok..but if I installed signalR, then i'm able to use websocket, no?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how SignalR works. It is not about installing a SignalR package and then being able to get any aspx page with websockets. SignalR is about creating a communication channel between the server and the client you could use to exchange data/messages and not to load web pages. I would recommend reading this introduction to SignalR: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr.